# How do I print out vectors in different order every time

Tags: c++, algorithm, random, vector

I'm trying to make two vectors. Where vector1 (total1) is containing some strings and vector2(total2) is containing some random unique numbers(that are between 0 and total1.size() - 1)

I want to make a program that print out total1s strings, but in different order every turn. I don't want to use iterators or something because I want to improve my problem solving capacity.

Here is the specific function that crash the program.

```
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < total1.size();)
{
    v1 = rand() % total1.size();
    for (unsigned s = 0; s < total1.size(); ++s)
    {
        if (v1 == total2[s])
            ;
        else
        {
            total2.push_back(v1);
            ++i;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm very grateful for any help that I can get!

Comment: is `total1` assigned to `total2` somewhere?

Comment: How do you guarantee that `total2.size() >= total1.size()`?

Comment: I only do ++i when I add something in total2. Doesn't that make sure that they will be in equal size?

Comment: Do you need permutations or just random order?

Comment: You could use [`std::suffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle)

Comment: LogicStuff: Just any random order is okey.
NathanOliver: Ye that would work but in the course I'm studying for we are not allowed to use anything from the standard library etc.

Comment: "we are not allowed to use anything from the standard library" - where does your prof think `std::vector<>` and `std::string` come from; faries? Using [`std::shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) with a generator from [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) is *exactly* how most engineers would solve this.  If you;re not allowed to, then create a vector of `int` with a sequence content of 0..size-1, implement a shuffle like [fisher-yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), and use it to index your original vector.

Comment: @AlfaBlommaN: what does "we are not allowed to use anything from the standard library" mean?  It's complete nonsense — or, at least, a radical misstatement of the constraints.  You aren't expected to write your own I/O functions (or memory management functions, etc.), are you?

Comment: 'In a different order every turn'…for how many turns, and on how big a set of values?  Ultimately, if you have N values, there are 'only' N! (factorial N) sequences possible, so you will repeat a previous sequence after that.  Do you have to verify that the sequence is different from each preceding sequence?  Fortunately for you, it is unlikely to be what is meant; you just need the sequences to be unpredictable.

Comment: _"I don't want to use iterators or something because I want to improve my problem solving capacity."_ That doesn't make sense. If you want to improve your problem solving capacity, then learn to solve your problems in the best way possible which, in this case, means using iterators. Setting out to do the least good thing possible is not useful.

Comment: @pasabaporaqui err yes - of course. A brain fault. I deleted my comment in shame. :-}

Answer (score 1):

Can I suggest you change of algorithm?. Because, even if your current one is correctly implemented ("s", in your code, must go from 0 to total**2**.size not total1.size and if element is found, break and generate a new random), it has the following drawback: assume vectors of 1.000.000 elements and you are trying the last random number. You have one probability in 1.000.000 of find a random number not previously used. That is a very small amount.Last but one number has a probability of 2 in 1.000.000 also small. In conclusion, your program will loop and expend lots of CPU resources.

Your best alternative is follow @NathanOliver suggestion and look for function `std::shuffle`. The manual page shows the implementation algorithm, that is what you are looking for.

Another simple algorithm, with some pros and cons, is:

1. init total2 with sequence 0,1,2,...,n where n is the size total1 - 1
2. choice two random numbers, i1 and i2, in range [0,n-1].
3. Swap elements i1 and i2 in total2.
4. repeat from (2) a fixed number of times "R".

This method allows to known a priori the necessary steps and to control the level of "randomness" of the final vector (bigger R is more random). However, it is far to be good in its randomness quality.

Another method, better in the probabilistic distribution:

1. fill a list `L` with number 0,1,2,...size total1-1.
2. choice a random number `i` between 0 and the size of list `L` - 1 .
3. Store in total2 the `i`-th element in list `L`.
4. Remove this element from `L`.
5. repeat from (2) until `L` is empty.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to shuffle `vector<string> total1`, you can do this without using helping `vector<int> total2`. Here is an implementation based on [Fisher–Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm).

```
for(int i=n-1; i>=1; i--) {
    int j=rand()%(i+1);
    swap(total1[j], total1[i]);  // your prof might not allow use of swap:)
}
```

If you must use `vector<int> total2` then shuffle it using above algorithm. Next you can use it to create a new `vector<string> result` from `total1` where `result[i]=total1[total2[i]]`.